# nginx - how to decrease speed for ip if too many requests

Tags: nginx

i have following configuration:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=300r/m;
…
server{
…
location / {
limit_req zone=one;
…
}
…
}
```

But i want to not show error page(503) for user, but just decrease speed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location / {
 if ($ips) {
  limit_rate 256k;
 }
}
```

Set `$ips` by using geo:

```
geo $ips {
 default    0;

 1.2.3.0/32 1; //edit ip address
}
```